# Why does DSUM work incorrectly in a Named Data Macro?

Tags: ms-access-2013, ms-access-data-macro

**SUMMARY:**

I am trying to use a named data macro with a DSUM to maintain a parents record's total of the child records.  When I edit the child record the data macro does change the parent record, but the result seems to be based on the old value's of the current record.

**DETAILS:**

I have a database similar to the Northwind Database from Microsoft.  A copy can be found at http://www.thetechmentors.com/freestuff/exerciseFiles/msAccess/DlookupDatamacroProblem2.zip.

It has tblOrder and tblOrderDetail.  The tblOrder has a named data macro that is called in the tblOrderDetail's After Update data macro.  The named data macro uses DSUM("Ext Price","tblOrderDetail", "Order ID" & @OrderID).  The data macro runs, but the results seem to be based on the child record's old value.

I discovered a work around.  Instead of using a DSUM I used a local variable and a "For Each Record In" Loop to calculate the correct sum.

While my work around works, I would still like to know why the DSUM approach did not work.  Any help you can provide is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Tom. This is just speculation on my part so don't assume this is exactly what is happening. In a data macro, all of the updates are essentially happening in memory in a process. If an error is hit, for example, the process stops. My guess with the DSum approach is that Access is essentially reading what is the current *committed* value to disk since the data macro hasn't completed all of its transaction work. Your approach of adding up the values in a ForEachRecord loop, assigning it to a variable, and then saving that value into the main parent record is the preferred method.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, that makes sense.  BTW: I recently purchased your "Access 2013 Inside Out" book.  Excellent material.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help Tom. Thanks for the nice comments on my book. Good luck with your Access projects.